# JAVA. Как получить значение поля JSON

Tags: java

У меня есть JSON ответ. Нужно получить значение поля duration. Как это реализовать? ЯП: Ява. Мне разобраться в джейсоне не хватает ума.

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"werwerwerwerwerwerwerwerwerwerwerwerwerwerwerwe\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"werwerwerwerwerwerwerwerwerwerwerwerwerwerwerwe\"",
   "id": "KD5wYlYHj_U",
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT9M59S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "false",
    "licensedContent": false,
    "projection": "rectangular"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: ну либо десериализовать в объект (что предпочтительно), либо парсить строку (чем не советую заниматься)

Comment: накидал тут ответ с использованием Jackson Object Mapper: https://hastebin.com/xajatiyola.cs